# QuickSight - How to calculate sum of rows with if statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, calculated-field

Given the following table I want to create another table with the total of video_duration and total duration of videos that have events
video can have numerous events, but the duration is of course the same per video file, hence I can have rows of the same video with different event but the video duration stay the same.

**input**

| filename | event | video_duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | RUN | 20 |
| A | WALK | 20 |
| B | FIGHT | 10 |
| B | RUN | 10 |
| C |  | 30 |
| D | WALK | 25 |
| D | FALL | 25 |
| E |  | 15 |

**desired output**

| total videos duration | videos with events duration |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 55 |

what I've tried:

I created a calculated field
`C_total_videos_duration = sum(max({video_duration, [filename]))`
which gave me the desired output (100). But, for gods sake, I can't figure out how to get the "videos without events duration".

I have tried:

`sumIf(max({video_duration}, [{filename}]), isNotNull({event}))` *ERROR: the calculation operated on LAC agg experssions is not valid*

`sum(maxIf({video_duration}, isNotNull({event})), [{filename}])`
*ERROR: Nesting of aggregate functions like NESTED_sum and NESTED_SUM(MAX(CASE WHEN "id" IS NOT NULL THEN video_duration ELSE NULL END), filename) is not allowed*

`ifelse(isNotNull({event}), sum(max({vide_`*`duration}, [{filename}])), 0)` ERROR: Mismatched aggregation. Custom aggregations can't contain both aggregate SUM and non-aggregated fields SUM(NESTEDMAX(video_duration, filename)) in any combination*

The only thing that partially work is

`sumOver(maxIf({video_duration},isNotNull(id)), [filename],POST_AGG_FILTER)`

but here I get:

| filename | total_videos_duration | videos_with_events_duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 20 |
| B | 10 | 10 |
| C | 30 |  |
| D | 25 | 25 |
| E | 15 |  |
| Total | 100 | 55 |

I don't this output because I have A LOT of videos, I just want to get the total durations

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out just now!
I did `sum(max(ifelse(isNotNull(id),{video_duration}, 0), [filename]))` and it worked.
Thank you stack!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).